# Leveraging a generic return type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, pattern-matching

So I would like to use a generic return type and be able to use the info of that type within the function. Not sure this is possible but here is what I would like:

```scala
  def getStuff[A](a: MyObj, b: String): Option[A] = {
    // do some stuff
    A match {
      case String => Some(a.getString(b))
      case Integer => Some(a.getInt(b))
      ...
      case _ => None
    }
  }
```

However, as you know, `A match` is not a possibility. Any ideas on how I could achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic case for using a typeclass:

```
trait StuffGetter[T] { // typeclass
  def get(obj: MyObj, s: String): Option[T]
}  

implicit val stringGetter = new StuffGetter[String] {
   def get(o: MyObj, s: String): Option[String] = ???
}
implicit val intGetter = new StuffGetter[Int] {
   def get(o: MyObj, s: String): Option[Int] = ???
}

def getStuff[A](a: MyObj, b: String)(implicit ev: StuffGetter[A]): Option[A] =
  ev.get(a, b)

val stuff0 = getStuff[String](obj, "Hello")  // calls get on stringGetter
val stuff1 = getStuff[Int](obj, "World") // call get on intGetter
val stuff2 = getStuff[Boolean](obj, "!") // Compile-time error
```

The `StuffGetter` trait defines the operations that you want to perform on the generic type, and each `implicit` value of that trait provides the implementation for a specific type. (For a custom type these are typically place in the companion object for the type; the compiler will look there for them)

When `getStuff` is called the compiler will look for an `implicit` instance of `StuffGetter` with the matching type. This will fail if no such instance exists, otherwise it will be passed in the `ev` parameter.

The advantage of this is that the "match" is done at compile time and unsupported types are also detected at compile time.

Comment: Just two cets there. In scala 3 it is possible to use also inline + erasedValue (as done here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ICi94Cy8QVOkZaOYBav4Lw). Anyway, I think implicit solution is always better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm afraid I don't speak Scala 3 but this will be useful for others!

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually we can differentiate between pattern matching at *run-time* which looks something like this

```
def getStuff[A](...) =
  A match {
    ...
  }
```

and pattern matching at *compile-time* which looks something like this

```
def getStuff[A](...)(implicit ev: Foo[A]) = {
   ev.bar(...)
}
```

Key concept to understand is that types do not exists at run-time because they get "erased" after compilation so there is not enough information to pattern match on types once the program is running. However at compile-time, that is before the program runs, types do exist and Scala provides means to ask the compiler to effectively pattern match on them via implicit/givens mechanism which looks something like so

```
// type class requirements for type A 
trait StringConverter[A] {
  def getOptValue(b: String): Option[A]
}

// evidence which types satisfy the type class 
implicit val intStringConverter: StringConverter[Int] = (b: String) => b.toIntOption
implicit val strStringConverter: StringConverter[String] = (b: String) => Some(b)
implicit def anyStringConverter[A]: StringConverter[A] = (b: String) => None

// compile-time pattern matching on type A
 def getStuff[A](b: String)(implicit ev: StringConverter[A]): Option[A] = {
   ev.getOptValue(b)
  }

getStuff[Int]("3")     // : Option[Int] = Some(value = 3)
getStuff[String]("3")  // : Option[String] = Some(value = "3")
getStuff[Double]("3")  // : Option[Double] = None
```

This compile-time pattern matching is called **type class** pattern.

Understanding the distinction between types and classes is one of the fundamental concepts in Scala https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#whats-the-difference-between-types-and-classes and gorking it will help understand how to write type classes.

Answer (score 2):

Using custom typeclass similar to [Getter](https://github.com/optics-dev/Monocle/blob/master/core/shared/src/main/scala/monocle/Getter.scala):

```
trait KeyedGetter[S, K, A]:
  def get(s: S, key: K): Option[A]

case class MyObj(ints: Map[String, Int], strs: Map[String, String])

object MyObj:
  given KeyedGetter[MyObj, String, Int] with
    def get(m: MyObj, k: String) = m.ints.get(k)

  given KeyedGetter[MyObj, String, String] with
    def get(m: MyObj, k: String) = m.strs.get(k)

def getStuff[A](m: MyObj, key: String)(using g: KeyedGetter[MyObj, String, A]): Option[A] =
  g.get(m, key)
```

Using class tags:

```
case class MyObj(ints: Map[String, Int], strs: Map[String, String])

import reflect._
def getStuff[A](m: MyObj, key: String)(using ct: ClassTag[A]): Option[A] = (ct match
  case _ if ct == classTag[String] => m.strs.get(key)
  case _ if ct == classTag[Int] => m.ints.get(key)
  case _ => None
).asInstanceOf[Option[A]]
```

If the erased types are insufficient, for a similar approach with type tags see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46706940/2707792) (and ignore the rest).